# CSV Reader Box in Openvibe gives the error: Error in file header

Tags: csv, header

I am trying to read a csv file in openvibe using csv reader box, but I get the error "error in header of the file". CSV file apparently follows the standard input file i.e., Time (s), channel 1, channel 2, ... , channel n, sampling rate. Can someone please help me solve it. I attached the error and csv file below.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this issue by considering:

1- Make sure your file header contains all columns as in: http://openvibe.inria.fr/csv-file-format-description/

2- Epoching should be done properly.